# Уменьшение разрешения разных изображений

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такая проблема: если загрузить изображение, у которого сторона **x** короче стороны **y**, то всё нормально, а если наоборот, то после загрузки остаётся пустое место. Как этого избежать?

Можно дописать атрибут `height=80`, но тогда изображения будут искажаться.

```css
.ava {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
}
```

```html
<div class="ava">
  <img src="http://i96.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0801/65/a6bf6064479f865c2d64e25e51243f65.jpg" width="80">
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="ava">
  <img src="http://i94.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0801/4d/758881cfff1c51e221bded6053b8564d.jpg" width="80">
  </div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/3c6f9ry6/

Answer (score 4):

`Object-fit` на данный момент не поддерживается в IE и Edge, поэтому могу порекомендовать `background-size:cover`:

```css
.ava {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="ava" style="background-image:url(http://i96.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0801/65/a6bf6064479f865c2d64e25e51243f65.jpg);"></div>

<br><br>

<div class="ava" style="background-image:url(http://i94.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0801/4d/758881cfff1c51e221bded6053b8564d.jpg);"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть такое прекрастное новое свойство `object-fit: cover`. Используйте с осторожностью 
https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

```css
.ava {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
}
.ava img {
width: 100%;
height:100%;
object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="ava">
  <img src="http://i96.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0801/65/a6bf6064479f865c2d64e25e51243f65.jpg" width="80">
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="ava">
  <img src="http://i94.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0801/4d/758881cfff1c51e221bded6053b8564d.jpg" width="80">
  </div>
```

Comment: спасибо, а как раньше, решали эту проблему, без object-fit?

Comment: Там нет поддержки IE, если что )

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/leeyoonhuor/pen/RovoYN - это один из примеров, как можно фиксить на ie проблему с `object-fit`